# GeoJSON at URL just stopped rendering markers

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

My web application creates a geojson file on the server dynamically and then renders it on a map. It was working yesterday but is not today.

I have read through the MapBox API and troubleshooting pages. And searched the StackOverflow archives. I initially suspected it may have been the result of a MapBox version upgrade, but I think I am up-to-date now, and the geojson data is still not rendering.
I have debugged the application to ensure that the geojson file is being included.
Here is the link to a page that has minimal (6) markers in its corresponding geojson file (http://webapps.fhsu.edu/ksHerp/account.aspx?o=33&t=101)... some pages have more than 3,000. All of the code can be viewed from the source, it is also posted below.

heading

```
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.3.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.3.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

map call syntax in page

```
                        <script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidHRhZ2dhcnQiLCJhIjoiY2lwZmp0emR2MDA1YnRhbmQ2aW8xdm9wZCJ9.XMq3bMhOjRit7wR3q7oIgQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container id
style: 'mapbox://styles/ttaggart/cj3ohbccw00192rlrtj18zdmv', //stylesheet location
center: [-98.328809, 38.5], // starting position
zoom: 5 // starting zoom
});
var url = 'http://webapps.fhsu.edu/ksHerp/geojson/101.geojson';
map.on('load', function () {
 window.setInterval(function () {
 map.getSource('markers').setData(url);
}, 2000);
 map.addSource('markers', { type: 'geojson', data: url });
map.addLayer({
"id": "markers",
"type": "symbol",
"source": "markers",
"layout": {
"icon-image": "{marker-symbol}-11",
"icon-allow-overlap": true,
"text-field": "{title}",
"text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
"text-offset": [0, 0.6],
"text-anchor": "top"
}
});
});
// When a click event occurs near a marker icon, open a popup at the location of
// the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
map.on('click', function (e) {
var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['markers'] });
if (!features.length) {
return;
}
var feature = features[0];
// Populate the popup and set its coordinates
// based on the feature found.
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .setHTML(feature.properties.description)
    .addTo(map);
});
// Use the same approach as above to indicate that the symbols are clickable
// by changing the cursor style to 'pointer'.
map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['markers'] });
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = (features.length) ? 'pointer' : '';
});
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
map.addControl(nav, 'top-right');
 </script>
```

Geojson file created and linked above

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-95.657787, 37.203811]},"properties": {"description": "<strong>Per. Obs</strong><p>Montgomery Co., Kansas: 37.203811, -95.657787: na: 6 Sep 2010 : James Erdmann: <br />From a message passed on to me by James Erdmann, of his sister being envenomated by a Cottonmouth at a family quarry SE of Independence. James, his brother, and I conducted a search on 10 June 2017 w/o success. James is a herpetologist, receiving his Masters at Southeastern Louisiana University in 2017. - Travis W. Taggart.</p>","marker-size": "small", "marker-color": "#ff0000", "marker-symbol": "triangle-stroked"}},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-95.078393, 37.034605]},"properties": {"description": "<strong>KU 23284</strong><p>Labette Co., Kansas: 37.034605, -95.078393: Neosho River E of Chetopa: : No date: ?: <br />In need of corroboration. -Travis W. Taggart, 6 June 2006.</p>","marker-size": "small", "marker-color": "#0000ff", "marker-symbol": "circle-stroked"}},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-94.677, 37.1632]},"properties": {"description": "<strong>KU 218780</strong><p>Cherokee Co., Kansas: 37.1632, -94.677: 1 mi S, 1.5 mi E jct US Rt 69, KS Rt 96; Sec 16 & 21,T33S,R25E: 29 Aug 1991 : K. Outt: <br />run over by vehicle near Shawnee Creek bridge; presumed dead, but envenomated collector when picked up.</p>","marker-size": "small", "marker-color": "#0000ff", "marker-symbol": "circle"}},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-94.642994, 37.178178]},"properties": {"description": "<strong>KU 218677</strong><p>Cherokee Co., Kansas: 37.178178, -94.642994: ca 1mi W Missouri border on Ks Rt 96 at Spring River,Sec 14,T33S,R25E: 14 Sep 1991 : Shane Eckhardt: <br />shot at base of tree near bridge over Spring River east of Crestline.</p>","marker-size": "small", "marker-color": "#0000ff", "marker-symbol": "circle"}},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-95.634436, 37.05989]},"properties": {"description": "<strong>KU 174719</strong><p>Montgomery Co., Kansas: 37.05989, -95.634436: W bank Verdigris River at Big Hill, N of Coffeyville: 23 Jun 1977 : ?: <br />data suspect; most certainly one of a number of specimens deliberately released in the Verdigris River between Independence and Coffeyville in the mid to late 1970s. Travis W. Taggart - 8/4/2012.</p>","marker-size": "small", "marker-color": "#0000ff", "marker-symbol": "circle-stroked"}},
{"type": "Feature","geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [-95.696097, 37.2252]},"properties": {"description": "<strong>KU 170521</strong><p>Montgomery Co., Kansas: 37.2252, -95.696097: Verdigris River, E of Independence, ca 366 m downstream: 26 Jul 1976 : ?: <br />data suspect; most certainly one of a number of specimens deliberately released in the Verdigris River between Independence and Coffeyville in the mid to late 1970s. Travis W. Taggart - 8/4/2012.</p>","marker-size": "small", "marker-color": "#0000ff", "marker-symbol": "circle-stroked"}}
]}
```

When working correctly, the locality markers specified in the geojson file are rendered as brown circles, triangles, and squares. There are no errors, the markers just don't show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it appears to be related with missing sprite images in style, in that case the following warning is getting displayed (refer [to this pull request](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/6831) for a more details):

> Image "..." could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the
>   image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You
>   can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing"
>   map event.

When switching, for example, to [Mapbox Streets](https://studio.mapbox.com/styles/mapbox/streets-v9/) style `mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9` markers are getting rendered as expected

[image]

For your style `mapbox://styles/ttaggart/cj3ohbccw00192rlrtj18zdmv` those image icons are missing:

- circle-11
- triangle-stroked-11
- circle-stroked-11

once the missing images are loaded, for example via [this technique](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-missing-generated/):

```
 map.on("styleimagemissing", e => {
    console.log("loading missing image: " + e.id);
    if (
      e.id === "circle-11" ||
      e.id === "triangle-stroked-11" ||
      e.id == "circle-stroked-11"
    ) {
      map.loadImage(e.id + ".png", (error, image) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        if (!map.hasImage(e.id)) map.addImage(e.id, image);
        map.getSource('markers').setData(url);
      });
    }
  });
```

the markers will appear on map

[image]

[Demo](https://glitch.com/~feather-agate)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but does the style you are using not support the marker icons being referenced?  I see a number of console warnings, which suggest that the markers are being plotted on the map but the icons don't load.

```
Image "park-11" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing" map event. util.js:329:52
Image "dot-9" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing" map event. util.js:329:52
Image "dot-10" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing" map event. util.js:329:52
Image "dot-11" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing" map event. util.js:329:52
Image "wetland" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing" map event.
```

Can you try setting to one of the default styles?

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#styles

```
mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11
mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11
mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10
mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10
mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9
mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11
mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-preview-day-v4
mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-preview-night-v4
mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-guidance-day-v4
mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-guidance-night-v4
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the style to 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11' but the markers are still not displaying. I tried a few other styles as well, w/o any luck.